# Urban Airship intermittent alert failures

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

Here is the problem I am experiencing:

1. I have 5 iOS devices provisioned for an ad hoc build for distribution via test flight.
2. Our UA ap is configured for production.
3. Using the Rich Push Broadcast tool from UA Console I send a rich push broadcast.
4. All 5 devices get the alert in the notification center.
5. I send another rich push broadcast.
6. All devices but #2 receive the alert in the notification center.
7. Sending another broadcast, All devices but #1 and #4 receive the alert in the notification center.
8. And so and so forth, with some push alerts being received by all devices and others with random failures to receive alerts. It should be noted that in each case, the pushes do appear in the UA Inbox.

There seems to be no rhyme or reason for these failures. I notice that there is a single error for a specific single device token for each push, regardless of the number of devices that failed to receive the alert in the error console.

Any ideas what could be causing this?